# Quarkus Docker JVM SSL issue

Tags: docker, ssl, jvm, quarkus

I have a quarkus app connecting to a MySQL database.

I use the generated Dockerfile.jvm to build my docker image. And I have no issue to run this image on my local desktop.

However when I want to run the same image on my vm, I have the following stacktrace:

```
Caused by: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure                                      
                                                                                                                                  
The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.  
  at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:174)                                       
  at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:64)                           
  at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:836)                                                        
  at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:456)                                                             
  at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:246)                                                        
  at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:197)                                                
  at io.agroal.pool.ConnectionFactory.createConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:200)                                                
  at io.agroal.pool.ConnectionPool$CreateConnectionTask.call(ConnectionPool.java:419)                                             
  at io.agroal.pool.ConnectionPool$CreateConnectionTask.call(ConnectionPool.java:401)                                             
  at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)                                                           
  at io.agroal.pool.util.PriorityScheduledExecutor.beforeExecute(PriorityScheduledExecutor.java:65)                               
  at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1126)                                    
  at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)                                    
  at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)                                                                              
Caused by: com.mysql.cj.exceptions.CJCommunicationsException: Communications link failure                                         
                                                                                                                                  
The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.  
  at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)                                     
  at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)              
  at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)      
  at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:490)                                                    
  at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:61)                                           
  at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:105)                                          
  at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:151)                                          
  at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createCommunicationsException(ExceptionFactory.java:167)                            
  at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeProtocol.negotiateSSLConnection(NativeProtocol.java:334)                                       
  at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeAuthenticationProvider.connect(NativeAuthenticationProvider.java:164)                          
  at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeProtocol.connect(NativeProtocol.java:1342)                                                     
  at com.mysql.cj.NativeSession.connect(NativeSession.java:157)                                                                   
  at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:956)                                                  
  at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:826)                                                        
  ... 11 more                                                                                                                     
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: No appropriate protocol (protocol is disabled or cipher suites are inappropriate) 
  at java.base/sun.security.ssl.HandshakeContext.<init>(HandshakeContext.java:171)                                                
  at java.base/sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshakeContext.<init>(ClientHandshakeContext.java:98)                                     
  at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.kickstart(TransportContext.java:222)                                             
  at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:433)                                              
  at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:411)                                              
  at com.mysql.cj.protocol.ExportControlled.performTlsHandshake(ExportControlled.java:336)                                        
  at com.mysql.cj.protocol.StandardSocketFactory.performTlsHandshake(StandardSocketFactory.java:188)                              
  at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeSocketConnection.performTlsHandshake(NativeSocketConnection.java:99)                           
  at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeProtocol.negotiateSSLConnection(NativeProtocol.java:325)                                       
  ... 16 more
```

I have no idea about how to solve this issue. Any help would be very appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my problem with replacing the original Dockerfile.jvm content by the following one:

```
FROM openjdk:11-jdk-slim
COPY target/lib/* lib/
COPY target/*.jar app.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","/app.jar"]
```

This maybe create heavier image, but at least this is always working.

Comment: Thanks so much for your solution, after over a week of work with that same issue i finally found your solution and it worked

Answer (score 0):

Just stumbled into this;
My quarkus container in running in ubi8 (rhel8) and connecting to mysql 5.7

https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_support_for_spring_boot/2.1/html/release_notes_for_spring_boot_2.1/known-issues-spring-boot

Just modify mysql jdbc url to "useSSL=true&enabledTLSProtocols=TLSv1.2"